# Replace Launch screen text on each app login

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I want to change the text of a label in the LaunchScreen.storyboard on each application launch. The problem is that when I am trying to set a UIViewController to the LaunchScreen.storyboard I get this error:

> "Launch screens may not set custom classnames".

My goal is to show the user hidden features of the app while he waits for it to load (every time a different one).

Comment: One way to achieve this is, create a view controller similar to your launch screen (just copy paste the launch screen view controller to your main storyboard). Set it as the root view controller and do stuffs in this page. Because this page is exactly similar to the launch page user won't get the feeling of navigating to another page.

Comment: Fair enough! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign custom VC to that launch (only static images or text dragged from Object Library ) , if you want to make splash make it in the rootVC then navigate to the mainVC

Comment: Thank you! I will make the change in my code